# SQL to C# LINQ query with multiple group by inner queries and having clauses

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a list with set of values. I wanted to check if the table has the matching values with the matching count using a `LINQ` query in `c#`

This is my list:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>()
        {
          130011,
          130010
        };
```

This is my table

```
RelEmployeeDepartments:

ID  EmpID DeptID
8   4     130011
9   4     130010
10  4     2
18  13    130011
19  13    130010
20  13    1
21  13    2
23  5     130011
24  5     130010
```

Now i wanted to find all the Employee's who are already assigned to the exact departments `list1` has along with the same count. So with the values in my `list1` the output shall be `EmpID` 5 as it has the same values and same count of departments. `EmpID` 4 & 13 shouldn't be in my output because even though there are matching departments for the employee, the count is different.

This is the working SQL query i came up with:

```
SELECT EmpID FROM 
RelEmployeeDepartments WHERE EmpID IN 
(SELECT red.EmpID FROM RelEmployeeDepartments red
GROUP BY red.EmpID HAVING COUNT(red.DeptID) = 2)
AND DeptID IN (130010,130011) 
GROUP BY EmpID HAVING COUNT(DeptID) = 2
```

I managed to get the inner query with `LINQ` like this but couldn't convert it fully.

```
var innerQuery = (from red in RelEmployeeDepartments 
                           group red by red.EmpID into red1
                           where red1.Count().Equals(list1.length)
                           select red1.Key);
```

I am wondering how can i convert this to a LINQ query or if there is even a better solution than above one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lot of struggle,help with @farzan-mirheydari answer and [Using linq to group a table that contains substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332644/using-linq-to-group-a-table-that-contains-substrings) this is my working solution.It's an exact conversion of my SQL query in the question

```
from red1 in RelEmployeeDepartments
where
 (from red in RelEmployeeDepartments group red by new {
   red.EmpID
  }
  into g where g.Count() == list1.Count() select new {
   g.Key.EmpID
  }).Contains(new {
  EmpID = red1.EmpID
 }) &&
 (list1).Contains(red1.DeptID)
group red1 by new {
 red1.EmpID
}
into g
where g.Count() == list1.Count()
select new {
 g.Key.EmpID
};
```

Lambda Code:

```
    RelEmployeeDepartments
   .Where(
    red1 =>
    (RelEmployeeDepartments
     .GroupBy(
      red =>
      new {
       EmpID = red.EmpID
      }
     )
     .Where(g => (g.Count() == list1.Count()))
     .Select(
      g =>
      new {
       EmpID = g.Key.EmpID
      }
     )
     .Contains(
      new {
       EmpID = red1.EmpID
      }
     ) &&
     list1.Contains(red1.DeptID)
    )
   )
   .GroupBy(
    red1 =>
    new {
     EmpID = red1.EmpID
    }
   )
   .Where(g => (g.Count() == list1.Count()))
   .Select(
    g =>
    new {
     EmpID = g.Key.EmpID
    }
   );
```

I know it looks complex. If there is a better or easier way, please post it.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a combination of `Contain`, `GroupBy`, and `Where` clauses:

```
var result = RelEmployeeDepartments
                 .Where(e => list1.Contains(e.DeptID))
                 .GroupBy(g => g.EmpId)
                 .Where(grp => grp.Count() == list1.Count())
```

above will give you `IGrouping`, you can then `Select` and `SelectMany` to get `IEnumerable<int>` of `EmpID`

```
result.Select(grp => grp.Select(v => v.EmpId)).SelectMany(x => x).Distinct()
```

Comment: This is giving me 4,5 & 13 too where as the output needs to be only 5

Comment: do you know whether it's returning all the three number due the  `.Where(...Contains...` failing or `.Where(...Count...` failing?

Comment: Its the issue with the count form whatever i see. This is the sql query i get from your LINQ query using LINQPad: DECLARE p0 Int = 130010
DECLARE p1 Int = 130011
DECLARE p2 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[EmpID]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[EmpID]
    FROM [RelEmployeeDepartments] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[DeptID] IN (p0, p1)
    GROUP BY [t0].[EmpID]
    ) AS [t1]
CROSS JOIN [RelEmployeeDepartments] AS [t2]
WHERE ([t1].[value] = p2) AND ([t1].[EmpID] = [t2].[EmpID]) AND ([t2].[DeptID] IN (p0, p1)); removed @ for variables as stackoverflow is not allowing.

Comment: that's odd, here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406978/2788979) suggesting the same solution. maybe try that notation ?

Comment: I got half part right this way , just needed to put a contains query some where. Can you take a look please ? from red in RelEmployeeDepartments 
                           group red by red.EmpID into red1
                           where red1.Count().Equals(list1.length)
                           select red1.Key

Comment: contains goes behind `group red by..` so something like `from red in RelEmployeeDepartments where list1.Contains(red.DeptID) group red ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173165/discussion-between-srini-and-farzan-mirheydari).